# Кто может оказать помощь в установке opensource проекта?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Есть опенсоурс проект Stf , они предполагают установку на linux подобные системы.Работаю из под windows, нашел у них вариант установки с помощью [vargant и virtual box.](https://github.com/openstf/setup-examples) 
Я так понимаю я приду к успеху и смогу , теоретически, заставить это работать на wundows 7. Но испытываю трудности . Нуждаюсь в вашей помощи . Может ли кто нибудь мне помочь ?  Или  описать шаги для установки . Спасибо .

Answer (score 1):

Если компьютер не ваш (вы не администратор), все это делать будет неудобно, я не рекомендовал бы.

Если компьютер ваш, установите любой простой в настройке linux, лучше всего последнюю версию Ubuntu. Сделать это можно с DVD-привода, если он есть, либо с USB-флешки. В случае флешки используется, например, программа linuxliveusb [здесь](https://www.linuxliveusb.com). Вы можете поставить linux рядом с Windows, а затем поставить нужный вам софт. Учитывая, что linux бесплатен, а VirtualBox никогда не будет работать с такой же производительностью, как сам linux, плюс он не увидит часть ваших периферийных устройств, не вижу смысла упираться в виртуальную машину и Windows. На современных дисках места для такой манипуляции бывает достаточно (вам потребуется до 25 Гб для Ubuntu 17.10). Процесс установки удобен, никаких требований к навыкам пользователя нет.

Как вариант, установите linux на отдельную флешку (лучше USB 3) или внешний жесткий диск.